# ESOCKETTIMEDOUT with remote CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

I'm running a CouchDB server with docker and I'm trying to POST data through a Node app.

But I'm frequently prompted with a ESOCKETTIMEDOUT error (not always).

Here's the way I'm opening the connexion to the DB:

```
var remoteDB = new PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/dsndatabase', {
  ajax: {
    cache: true,
    timeout: 40000 // I tried a lot of durations
  }
});
```

And here's the code used to send the data :

```
exports.sendDatas = function(datas,db, time) {
  console.log('> Export vers CouchDB')
  db.bulkDocs(datas).then(function () {
    return db.allDocs({include_docs: true});
  }).then(function (){
    var elapsedTime = new Date().getTime() - time;
    console.log('> Export terminé en ', elapsedTime, ' ms');
  }).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  })
};
```

The error doesn't show up every time but I'm unable to find a pattern.

And, timeout or not, all my data is successfully loaded in my CouchDB !

I've seen a lot of posts on this issue but none of them really answers my question ...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this seems to be real issue:
https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/3550#issuecomment-75100690

I think you can fix it by stating a reasonably longer timeout value/a retry logic using exponential backoff.

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Also I am curious why you are calling `db.allDocs({include_docs: true});`. Isn't that heavy ? You could use the replication API to send your docs over. There, the retry mechanism is in-built I read.

Comment: I removed the .allDocs() and set the timeout option of the constructor to 1 minute...

It seems to work now ... thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome .. : )  Please upvote the answer if you think it helped you out.